# Beginning Design as a Programmer

Tags: learning, books, coding, html, resources

I'm just starting to get in to web development. I'm learning Rails at the moment. I have lots of experience with various programming languages.

I've been searching for books to help me get started; I want to focus on writing clean, standards-compliant HTML and CSS.

Does anyone know of any modern, standards-based resources I can use, particularly books?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If your focus is clean HTML and CSS, you probably can't do any better than

## [CSS Mastery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223979)

[image: CSS Mastery cover]

It's written by some of the most influential CSS experts from the last several years.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that trying to duplicate existing site designs is a great way to learn graphics and CSS techniques.

For instance, sites like http://microsoft.com and http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/ are built around software products, but both do things a little differently.  Understanding what is going on here, as well as the audience they are trying to reach will help you as well.

Find a site you like and see how well you can duplicate it.

Also, for CSS practice http://csszengarden.com is nice and follows the advice above.